# "He told me that he and Oney, by virtue of several trips to the drunk farm, were medical wards of the state of California."

Tags: meaning-in-context

I am unable to understand the meaning of this sentence

> He told me that he and Oney, by virtue of several trips to the drunk farm, were medical wards of the state of California. (*The Last Good Kiss*)

Can you please tell me the meaning of it?

Comment: Hello Sabtaab.  You should add 2 pieces of information to your question

Comment: Firstly add the source of the quote.  The best way is to put a link to an online source.  If not, at least add the name of the book and the name of the author.

Comment: Secondly you need to explain why this is difficult to understand.  Do you know what "He told me that...." means (this is reported speech).  Do you know what "by virtue"  or "drunk farm" or "State of California"  mean?  Have you used a dictionary.   Don't say "of course I used a dictionary. Because if you have you need to tell us what you found."

Comment: You can use [edit] to add this information to your question.  When you have [edit]ed you can write a comment here to say it has been done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A ward of the state is a person who has been legally declared (by a court) to be unable to look after themselves. This could be because of mental disability or illness, or for a medical reason. The court appoints a guardian to look after the person's money and make decisions on their behalf. It seems that in California people who have been forcibly detained for drunkenness can be made medical wards.